# (VBA Excel) Capturing any instance of a specific key press in external application?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm often tasked with having to paste information from excel into various forms. I would save time if I did not have to switch windows between copying and paste. My idea is to press a button to activate a macro so it will copy the first cell, check if any instance of ctrl-v was executed in another application, then copy the next cell in the column. Is this possible?

To give you an idea of what I would like is this example:

```
Dim rownum As Integer
Dim copiedtext As String
Sub Button1_Click()
rownum = 2
copiedtext = Range("B" & rownum).Value
Application.OnKey "^v", "ABC"
End Sub

Sub ABC()
ActiveCell.Value = copiedtext
rownum = rownum + 1
copiedtext = Range("B" & rownum).Value
End Sub
```

Of course in this example, it's only finding the keypress in the same application but hopefully the idea of how I wish it to work is explained properly. Thanks for any help!

Comment: as the object context in `Application.OnKey` implies, the `OnKey` only traps key presses within Excel; interfacing with other applications is still "relatively" easy when objects exist in any library (like Word, Internet Explorer etc.) that can be referenced ... even without use of `OnKey` and `SendKey`

Comment: You can't really listen for keys pressed in a 3rd party (Not MS-Office) app from Excel...

Comment: What is the "other application"? Otherwise, Alt-Tab is your friend.